# Triggering docker run from another docker container

Tags: docker

I have two docker images, lets say

Image 1: This has an public API built on Python Flask
Image 2: This some functional tests written Python

I am looking for an option where the API in Image 1 container is posted with a specific param then the Image1 container should trigger a docker run of Image2.

Is this should to trigger a docker run from a docker container.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you mount as a volume the docker socket which will allow you to run, build and destroy containers?

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about using Docker in Docker

Check out this blog post for more info about how it works:
https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

in short, you need to mount the docker socket as a volume (and now with docker 1.10, its dependencies as well)

then you can run docker in docker.

but it seems like what you are trying to do does not necessarily require that. you should rather look into making your 'worker' API an actual HTTP API that you can run and call an endpoint for to trigger the parametrized work. That way you run a container that waits for work requests and run them, without running a container each time you need a task done.